# The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process (Error occur after numbers of files)

Tags: vb.net, ioexception

I have some emails with attachments sending out. Every 56th mail will go error. And the detail of the error is:

> System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Failure sending mail. --->
> System.IO.IOException: Unable to write data to the transport
> connection: An established connection was aborted by the software in
> your host machine. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An
> established connection was aborted by the software in your host
> machine    at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Send(Byte[] buffer, Int32
> offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)    at
> System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset,
> Int32 size)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
> System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset,
> Int32 size)    at System.Net.DelegatedStream.Write(Byte[] buffer,
> Int32 offset, Int32 count)    at
> System.Net.DelegatedStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32
> count)    at System.Net.Mime.SevenBitStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32
> offset, Int32 count)    at System.Net.DelegatedStream.Write(Byte[]
> buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)    at
> System.Net.DelegatedStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32
> count)    at System.Net.Mime.SevenBitStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32
> offset, Int32 count)    at System.Net.DelegatedStream.Write(Byte[]
> buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)    at
> System.Net.DelegatedStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32
> count)    at System.Net.Base64Stream.FlushInternal()    at
> System.Net.Base64Stream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32
> count)    at System.Net.Mime.MimePart.Send(BaseWriter writer)    at
> System.Net.Mime.MimeMultiPart.Send(BaseWriter writer)    at
> System.Net.Mail.Message.Send(BaseWriter writer, Boolean sendEnvelope)
> at System.Net.Mail.MailMessage.Send(BaseWriter writer, Boolean
> sendEnvelope)    at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage
> message)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
> System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)

I have find some similar answer in google but it is not working. Can anyone help please? I am using .NET 3.5 which could not use `SmtpClient.Dispose()`
Here is the similar question:
[Dispose method for smtpclient in .net 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45003909/dispose-method-for-smtpclient-in-net-2-0)

Comment: I'm not sure that disposing the `Attachments` collection is enough. You may have to dispose each `Attachment` object. I would suggest creating them with a `Using` statement, so they will be implicitly disposed at the end of the block. Also, setting a local variable to `Nothing` is pointless as it will cease to exist at the end of the block anyway.

Comment: I agree with @John, try using the `Using` blocks.

Comment: I updated my codes. And here is the error, System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Failure sending mail. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to write data to the transport connection: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I find the answer for my question. It works prefectly for disposing the smtpclient for the previous .net.

[Does system.net.mail.smptclient disconnect from the server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364501/does-system-net-mail-smptclient-disconnect-from-the-server)

Here is the code

```
var smtp = new SmtpClient();
smtp.ServicePoint.MaxIdleTime = 1;
smtp.ServicePoint.ConnectionLimit = 1;
smtp.Send(message);
```